# Vue.js Bundling to a single file

Tags: vue.js

I have an application that was developed using `Vue.js` . can any one suggest me how to bundle it to a single file component like `bundlejs`

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli ?

Comment: Use Webpack. Vue offers an amazing plugin for Webpack that gives you the ability to use .vue files to handle your code. It's awesome. Use vue-cli to create a sample project, use the webpack-simple version and build your app based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of solutions to bundling. My personal favorite is webpack though: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple

Answer (score 0):

Use vue-cli with webpack template (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli)

```
 vue init webpack my-project
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Install yarn.

Step 2. cd to the project directory.

Step 3. run command `yarn wps run localhost:80`